# subclass object used as parameters which are defined as base class type C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, factory

I read an example in the book of 'design pattern':

```
Maze* MazeGame::CreateMaze(MazeFactory& factory)
{
  //something to do 
}

class BombedMazeFactory :public MazeFactory
{
  //something to defined
}

int main()
{
   MazeGame game;
   BombedMazeFactory factory;
   game.CreateMaze(factory);
}
```

So, the subclass object will be send to CreateMaze() that uses the baseclass as parameter. What should I be careful, when I doing this kind of operations?

I am also not clear why sometimes the subclass functions are still virtual (they are virtual functions in base class), are there some advantages for this?

Thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in order to be able to reuse the same code for many different classes. In this case you can use in the CreateMaze() function many different factories.

The keyword virtual is optional in the inheriting class. If it is there or if it is not there, the method will be virtual because you're overriding the base class's method. Personally I prefer to use it in the inheriting class too to show it is virtual and not a regular method.